# Generating chi-square data

Tags: r

I would like to generate data following chi-square distribution with N=30 population. However I don't know if it is correct:

```
dchisq(1, df = 1:30)
#  [1] 2.419707e-01 3.032653e-01 2.419707e-01 1.516327e-01 8.065691e-02
#  [6] 3.790817e-02 1.613138e-02 6.318028e-03 2.304483e-03 7.897535e-04
# [11] 2.560537e-04 7.897535e-05 2.327761e-05 6.581279e-06 1.790585e-06
# [16] 4.700913e-07 1.193723e-07 2.938071e-08 7.021903e-09 1.632262e-09
# [21] 3.695738e-10 8.161308e-11 1.759875e-11 3.709686e-12 7.651632e-13
# [26] 1.545702e-13 3.060653e-14 5.945009e-15 1.133575e-15 2.123217e-16
```

Comment: Please read the help page, and you'll see you are not using the correct function.

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to generate 30 random Chi-Squared variables, you need to use the `rchisq()` function.

```
rchisq(n, df, ncp = 0)
```

So you would replace `n` with 30 and the `df` with the number of degrees of freedom you require. You can read more [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Chisquare.html).